Should there be a Lego Masters tag?
So, the second season of the Australian reality TV show Lego Masters has started, and apparently it's based off of similar shows that ran on British and American television under the same name. There doesn't currently seem to be a tag for these Lego Masters television shows; should we add one, so that people can ask questions about them? I could see questions like "How do I do this thing I saw someone do on Episode X of Season Y of the Australian Lego Masters show" or "Is it possible to get parts lists to make copies of the builds for Lego Masters" being on topic for this stack.

Generally tags are only added when there is a demand for them. If someone asks a question about LEGO Masters and they have the privilege to do create a new tag at 150 reputation, they may do so. If they do not have the required rep, they can make a comment, or flag their post to have a tag added.
Please note that new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
I don't believe there is a way to create a tag without having it included in a question.
